# Powershell giving wrong output in if else block

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Check the following code with simple `if else` blocks

```
cls
$a = Read-Host("Enter the marks ")

if (($a -le 100) -and ($a -ge 90)){

 Write-Host("The grade is A")

}
elseif (($a -le 89) -and ($a -ge 80)){

 Write-Host("The grade is B")

}

elseif (($a -le 79) -and ($a -ge 70)){

 Write-Host("The grade is C")

}

elseif (($a -le 69) -and ($a -ge 60)){

 Write-Host("The grade is D")

}
elseif($a -lt 60){
Write-Host("The grade is F")
}
```

And when I give input between `90 - 99` it returns without any output. And if I give `100` as input, I am getting `"The grade is F"`, ie, the `else` block is executed, but it should not work according to the code. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the issue is the data type. By default the data type is "String". The requirement here is to compare numbers hence the below solution to mark data type as 'int' is appropriate.

```
cls
[int]$a = Read-Host("Enter the marks ")
if (($a -le 100) -and ($a -ge 90)){
 Write-Host("The grade is A")
}
elseif (($a -le 89) -and ($a -ge 80)){
 Write-Host("The grade is B")
}
elseif (($a -le 79) -and ($a -ge 70)){
 Write-Host("The grade is C")
}
elseif (($a -le 69) -and ($a -ge 60)){
 Write-Host("The grade is D")
}
elseif($a -lt 60){
Write-Host("The grade is F")
}
```

I like it better

```
& {
    param(
        [ValidateRange(1, 100)]
        [int]$a
    )

    switch ($a){
        {$_ -in 90..100}{Write-Host("The grade is A")}
        {$_ -in 80..89}{Write-Host("The grade is B")}
        {$_ -in 70..79}{Write-Host("The grade is C")}
        {$_ -in 60..69}{Write-Host("The grade is D")}
        default {Write-Host("The grade is D")}
    }
    
} -a 95
```

```
$numberInString = Read-Host "imput number well be string"

    $numberInString -le 100
    [int]$numberInString -le 100

    $numberInString -ge 90
    [int]$numberInString -le 100

imput number well be sting: 95
False
True
True
True
```

If mark entered is say "99". Looking at the first comparison:

```
"99" -le "100"
```

The reason above result is "False" because "9" is greater than "1". String comparison occurs by comparing character by character until one or both strings reach end.

Comment: Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: @RoshinRaphel, by default the type is String. If you add a line "$a.GetType()" after you read it, you can see the type. Same way when type is specified it is int

Comment: @sunilvijendra So why is it working for all other cases outside the range `90-100`

Comment: Please [edit] the answer and explain there why hand how comparing string "100" and int 100 provide the outcome. As of now, the answer tells how but not why - so it doesn't yet support understanding the actual issue.